# Add class on cck image field(img tag)

Tags: 7, entities, media

I want to add a class on cck image field output img tag, not on field wrapper div.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Field Formatter CSS Class](https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) module for this. Module page says :

> The Field formatter CSS class module allows you to set any
>   text/list/option/taxonomy field to render as CSS class on the node.
>   This enables the node author to select predefined CSS styling per
>   node.

Comment: I tried this but it adds a class on image wrapper div not on img tag.